# projectile motion (with height) complicated

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

> When a child standing on a horizontal path throws a ball, it leaves
>   her hand from a point that is 90cm vertically above the path. The ball
>   clears a 4.5 m high wall that is 10.5 m away from where it was thrown.
>
> Show that the least velocity required for this to occur is the same as
>   the velocity acquired by a body falling 7.35m under gravity.

My solution :

Case1 : 7.35m falling body

$$
v^2=u^2+2as \\
v^2=0+2(-9.8)(-7.35) \\
v=\sqrt{144.06} \\
v=12 \, \mbox{m}/\mbox{s}
$$

Case 2: projectile motion

$$
t=0 \Rightarrow \\
\mathbf{V} = u \cos \alpha \, \mathbf{i} + u \sin \alpha \, \mathbf{j} \\ 
\mathbf{r} = 0.9 \, \mathbf{j}
$$

$$
\mathbf{V} = u \cos \alpha \, \mathbf{i} + 
[ u \sin\alpha -9.8t] \, \mathbf{j} \\
\mathbf{r}= (u\cos \alpha t) \, \mathbf{i} +
(0.9+ u \sin \alpha t-4.9 t^2) \, \mathbf{j} 
$$

I end up with the equations:

usina-9.8t=0
u=(9.8t)/sina......1

10.5=ucosat......2

4.50.9+usinat-4.9t^2......3

---

wrong answer where i let a=45 
let angle a=45
0.9+usin(45)t-4.9t^2=4.5_________1
ucos(45)t=10.5  => y=10.5/[cos(45)*t]

sub 2 to 1 
-4.9t^2+10.5/[cos(45)*t]*sin(45)*t-3.6=0
-4.9t^2+10.5tan(45)-3.6=0
-4.9t^2=-6.9
t=1.1867

so y=10.5/[cos(45)*1.1867]
=12.51

wrong answer^

---

which is... not  = to 12

Comment: Why $\alpha=45^0$

Comment: Can you give the title of your textbook ?

Comment: i don't know which textbook this come from

Comment: a=45degree because the ques said least velocity required

Comment: How do you know that a=45 degrees gives you the least velocity? In fact, I think a=45 might not give you the least velocity.k

Comment: thanks for that helpful comment

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile

Comment: @mvw and @ Yaitzme i ends up with three equations

Comment: @mvw thanks for the edit :)

Comment: You can solve it with Lagrangian multipliers and minimization. If $\theta$ is the angle above the horizontal, you're minimizing $v=\frac{10.5}{t\cos (\theta )}$ with the constraints $t>0$, $0<\theta <\frac{\pi}{2}$, $4.5<0.9+10.5\tan (\theta )-\frac{9.8}{2}t^2$ (coming from just basic kinematics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$v = u \cos(α)\vec{i} + u \sin(α)\vec{j}$

Now, for $v$ to be valid, either $\frac{3.6}{u\sin(α)} = \frac{10.5}{u\cos(α)}$ which gives  $α=18.92$

Or, $u\sin(α)t - 0.5 g t^2 = 3.6$ and $t=\frac{10.5}{u\cos(α)}$

Using these two equations, you can obtain the minimum $v$ required.
The basic concept is that if, time taken to reach the wall is $t$, $t \times v_{\tiny \mbox{horiz}} = 10.5$ and $v_{\tiny \mbox{vert}} \times t - 0.5 g t^2 = 3.6$

Comment: t = 1sec, 
a = 18.92 degree, 
velocity = 11.77 m/s (versus 12.0 m/s??)

Comment: from part b the ques is If the ball clears the wall, how far past the wall will it first strike the path? Which if i ends up with 0=0.9+11.09sin(18.92)t-4.9t^2 -> ends up with t=-0.2 or 0.93

Comment: and the ans for part b is 11.09cos(18.92)*0.93=9.756 (which is a bit far away from the answer 14.51)

Comment: @carry I can tell you the correct answer matches to the velocity of the 7.35m fall to at least 6 digits. (12.0025...)

Comment: $\frac{3.6}{u\sin(α)} = \frac{10.5}{u\cos(α)}$ <- how do u get this?

Comment: Time taken for 3.6 vertical displacement is same time taken for 10.5m hori disp.